# Calculate the row value based on different formula

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate the cell values based on the given formula in each row.

Input record is:

[image: Row level formula table]

Expected ouput is:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: what is the logic for selecting audience_2 and audience_3

Comment: It can be any combination, row wise calculation (result column) should happen based on the formula given in the row_cal. Formula can change for each row in this column

Comment: You will required to parse the formula, compute it and such task are not easy to implement in `SQL Server`

Comment: each `sl` is unique, only one row in your table?

Comment: yes, it is unique value and identity column

Comment: If there are a limited number of possible values for row_col, then you can use a case statement. Otherwise you will have to use dynamic SQL within a cursor. Please note that SUM is an aggregate function in SQL, whereas your examples are simple addition. If you go down the dynamic SQL route, you will have to strip out the SUM() if you leave your row_col like this.

Comment: @Squirrel : Yes, I guess it needs to parse through a function which can results for each row. But implementation is bit tricky. Can i achieve through any dynamic sql

Comment: Note : You can't use `dynamic sql` inside a `function`

Comment: This has the earmarks of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). There may be a much better solution to the larger problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is your formula is not correct. As I understand there is unique row for each `sl`. And to do the `sum` of `col1` and `col2` correct formula is `(col1 + col2)`. So correct that thing first.

After that you may implement this using dynamic sql as

```
create table tab_sum ( id int, col1 int, col2 int, col varchar(max) )

insert into tab_sum ( id, col1, col2, col )
values ( 1, 3, 5, '(col1 + col2)' )
, ( 2, 4, 6, '(col1 + col2)' )


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WITH CTE_DistinctFormulas AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col as Formula FROM tab_sum
)
SELECT @query = @query + '
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, col1, col2, col, ' + Formula + ' AS CalcValue FROM tab_sum WHERE col = ''' + Formula + ''' ' 
FROM CTE_DistinctFormulas;
SET @query = STUFF(@query,1,12,'');

PRINT @query;

EXEC (@query);
```

Or if editing formula is not an option for you then you may try this, But make sure you have only one row for each id and its corresponding values otherwise it will sum all of the similar rows in one.

```
create table tab_sum ( id int, col1 int, col2 int, col varchar(max) )

insert into tab_sum ( id, col1, col2, col )
values ( 1, 3, 5, 'sum(col1 + col2)' )
, ( 2, 4, 6, 'sum(col1 + col2)' )


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WITH CTE_DistinctFormulas AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col as Formula FROM tab_sum
)
SELECT @query = @query + '
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, col1, col2, col, ' + Formula + ' AS CalcValue FROM tab_sum WHERE col = ''' + Formula + ''' group by id, col1, col2, col ' 
FROM CTE_DistinctFormulas;
SET @query = STUFF(@query,1,12,'');

PRINT @query;

EXEC (@query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the case/ when expression? See MS doc: [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

So your query would be somthing like:

```
SELECT sl, audience_1, audience_2, audience_3,
   CASE WHEN audience_3 > 0 THEN audience_1 + audience_3
        ELSE audience_1 + audience_2
        END audience_total
FROM audience
;
```

You did not provide the criteria, so I had to guess :-)

(I did not run the query since I had no server handy :-) )

**UPDATE after comment by OP:**

If you have 71 different columns for audience in the same table you have a differnt issue imho.

Then my solution would be:

- split out the audience number to a detail table with `sl`,
  `audience_type` and audience_count
- create a `audience_calc_config` table with two columns `calc_method` and `audience_type`
- for each different calculation and audience type add an entry to the above
  table
- remove formula from original table and replace with appropriate
  calc_method
- Then run a simple select with a `JOIN`, `GROUP BY sl` and `SUM(audience)`
- (Of course it would be even nicer to split the audience_calc to a
  master/ detail, so you can have a foreign key...)

Comment: It has to be generic and case cannot depend on the row value (which can change at any time). I have 71 audience categories and case statement may not help as the formula in the base table can change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select *,case when row_cal like '%1%' and  row_cal like '%2%'  then value1 + value2 
                        when row_cal like '%1%' and  row_cal like '%3%'  then value1 + value3
                      end as result from YourTable
```